# writing a CoffeeScript Class

Tags: class, coffeescript

I have the following simple CoffeeScript Class:

```
class Country
    constructor: (@val) ->
        console.log @val
    foreign: ->
        @val isnt "United States"
    domestic: ->
        not foreign()
```

I have this simple class to determine some logic for a select drop down.

Here is how I am calling it:

```
$country = new Country($val) if $('select[id*="country"]').val() > 0
console.log $country.foreign? if $country?
```

`$val` is being set in an `on('change')` event. `$country.foreign?` is always evaluating to true even if I select a country other than the US. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. The @val is being set to the value I am passing in, but the foreign function isn't working properly

Comment: It's working fine for me here:   http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Country%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3A%20(%40val)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%40val%0A%20%20%20%20foreign%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40val%20isnt%20%22United%20States%22%0A%20%20%20%20domestic%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20not%20foreign()%0A%0Ac1%3D%20new%20Country(%22United%20States%22)%0Ac2%3D%20new%20Country(%22Not%20United%20States%22)%0A%0Aalert%20%22should%20be%20false%3A%20%23%7Bc1.foreign()%7D%22%0Aalert%20%22should%20be%20true%3A%20%23%7Bc2.foreign()%7D%22  Edit - Oh I see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
console.log $country.foreign()? if $country?
```

`foreign` is a function call.

Also that translates to this:

```
if (typeof $country !== "undefined" && $country !== null) {
  console.log($country.foreign() != null);
}
```

So you get a log of whether or not the return is null, you probably want to drop the `?`

```
console.log $country.foreign() if $country?
```

Comment: @dennismonsewicz Try dropping the `?` on the console.log call

Comment: That was it! I keep forgetting the the question mark in CoffeeScript is for existence...

Answer (score 1):

It should be $country.foreign()?